# Percent change from one column to the next

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I had a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[3, 2, 1], [5, 4, 2]])

3 2 1
5 4 2
```

I want to return a dataframe that has the percent change from one column to the next. So the above dataset would return:

```
.666 .5
.8   .5
```

How would I accomplish this in pandas?

Comment: The first percentage change is .333 right (3-2)/3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas has a function for this. Use [pct_change](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html):

```
df.pct_change(axis='columns')
```

This will output the 'percentage change' (per your question) from one column to other. Not the division of one column to the other (seems to be your example).

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed.

My example sucks. I can't math :)

Answer (score 0):

Not a very ideal way but works.

```
df['diff_1_0']=abs(df[0]-df[1])/df[0]
df['diff_2_1']=abs(df[1]-df[2])/df[1]
df=df[['diff_1_0','diff_2_1']]
```

If you have a lot of columns you can make it into a loop like below.

```
column_count=df.shape[1]+1
column_names=df.columns
for columns in df:
    if columns==0:
        continue
    else:
        df.insert(columns, str('diff_'+str(column_count)), abs(df[columns-1]-df[columns])/df[columns-1])
        column_count=column_count+1
df=df.drop(column_names, axis=1)
```

Hope it helps!